# mysql comparing 2 tables in within a group

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables

```
table A                      table B

pid date1                 pid date 2
a   10-12-2014            a   10-12-2014
a   11-13-2014            a   11-22-2011
                          a   8-9-2007
                          a   7-6-2006


b   9-10-2011             b  8-8-2011
                          b  9-5-2004
                          b  8-2-2005


c   8-8-2011              c 9-10-2001
                          c 8-8-2011
```

I want to check if a particular date1 has an entry in  date 2  for a particular pid

for ex for `pid` a the date1 `10-12-2014` exits in date 2 `10-12-2014` .

Comment: Don't you need only an inner join on pod and dates?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.*, IF(b.pid IS NULL, false, true) entry_in_b FROM taba a
LEFT JOIN tabb b ON a.pid = b.pid AND a.date1 = b.date2
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

This query will return all rows from `Table A` that have a matching `pid` and `date2` in `Table B`:

```
SELECT  A.pid,
        A.date1
  FROM  [Table A] A
    INNER JOIN [Table B] B ON B.pid = A.pid AND B.date2 = A.date1
```

If you want to return all rows from `A` and an indication of whether there is a matching row in `B`:

```
SELECT  A.pid,
        A.date1,
        CASE
          WHEN B.date2 IS NULL THEN 'no match'
          ELSE 'match'
        END AS Match
  FROM  [Table A] A
    LEFT JOIN [Table B] B ON B.pid = A.pid AND B.date2 = A.date1
```